# How to return a column value based on columns across multiple worksheets?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need to get a status with two conditions from separate worksheets or workbooks. I have an ID column, a Location column, and a Status column (column A (ID), column B (Loc), column C (Status)).

When ID and location criteria are met, it should return the value of the Status column for that row. E.g. if this were a SQL query:

```
SELECT Status from Source where IDsource=IDDestination && LocSource=LocDestination
```

How can I accomplish this?

I tried an `if(and))` formula but to no avail.

Comment: Can you post sample data please?

Comment: Hi Edeki, unfortunately i am not able to upload anything using this machine. Basically it is just 3 similar columns in 2 different sheets. ColumnA (ID), Column B (Location), Column C (Status).... Destination sheet has a blank status which it needs to get from Source sheet.

Comment: You can just insert a simple ascii table. No need for fancy uploads.

Comment: Use the [Range.AutoFilter method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter) to filter by `ID` and `Destination` and then loop through the filtered list with VBA (you will find tutorials and examples for this) to get your `Status` of the filter result. • If you have no idea [start using filters](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/filter-data-in-a-range-or-table-01832226-31b5-4568-8806-38c37dcc180e) manually and [record it as a macro](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/automate-tasks-with-the-macro-recorder-974ef220-f716-4e01-b015-3ea70e64937b).

Comment: You can also simply add a column in which you join ID and Location, then you can search for a simple match using vlookup()

Comment: @Luuklag This is a nice short workaround if the ID/Location combination is unique.

Comment: You can make a simple table using stacks interface. No need to upload.

Comment: hi guys, i was able to make it work! i concatenated the 2 columns which return a unique value and the lookup is good enough: Luuklag, thanks, i just did something like that and it totally works!

Comment: You can also use a 2 criteria `Index/Match` formula (solutions can be found on this website) to do this without a helper column, but @Luuklag solution will be easier to implement

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, yes that is indeed something to be cautious about. Otherwise results will be impredictable.

Comment: @Luuklag i just concatenated the ID and location to comeup with 11111NewYork then do the vlookup then delimited to put both sheets to in its original form. thanks so much.

Comment: @wh3resmycar2, I added it as an answer.

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

If you concatenate (or join) the ID and Location column in a new column you can do a simple `vlookup()`.

So if your "database" sheet looks like:

```
ID   | Location | Status    
------------------------
  1  |  Home    |   OK
  2  |  Home    |  Broken
  3  |  Work    |   OK
```

Then simple add another column in between Location and Status like this using the following formula: `=A1&"-"&B1` in C1.

```
ID   | Location | ID-Location | Status    
--------------------------------------
  1  |  Home    |   1-Home    |   OK
  2  |  Home    |   2-Home    |  Broken
  3  |  Work    |   3-Work    |   OK
```

If you then need the status of ID 1 and Location Home you simply do:
`=Vlookup(A2&"-"&B2,Database!C2:D1000,2,FALSE)` in cell C2 of your other sheet.

**If multiple combinations exist, only first match is returned.**

Answer (score 0):

An array formula like the following would do:

```
{=OFFSET(C:C;MIN(IF((A:A="Some ID")*(B:B="Some Location");ROW(C:C);""))-1;0;1;1)}
```

It gets a little heavy, but if you can limit row count, it gets faster:

```
{=OFFSET(C:C;MIN(IF((A2:A1001="Some ID")*(B2:B1001="Some Location");ROW(C2:C1001);""))-1;0;1;1)}
```