# How to apply VLOOKUP over a range

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have two tables. Table1 has `Names` and `Marks`. Table2 has a mark `Range` and corresponding `Grade`

I want to add column `Grade` in Table1 depending upon the `Marks` scored

Table1

```
+------+-------+
| Name | Marks |
+------+-------+
| Ab   |    98 |
| Bb   |    93 |
| Cc   |    87 |
| Dd   |    72 |
+------+-------+
```

Table2

```
+--------+-------+
| Range  | Grade |
+--------+-------+
| 91-100 | A     |
| 81-90  | B     |
| 71-80  | C     |
+--------+-------+
```

My desired output

```
| Name | Marks | Grade |
+------+-------+-------+
| Ab   |    98 | A     |
| Bb   |    93 | A     |
| Cc   |    87 | B     |
| Dd   |    72 | C     |
+------+-------+-------+
```

How do I do it with `VLOOKUP`, if not `VLOOKUP` what are other good alternatives except for marcros/vba

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return a column value based on columns across multiple worksheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54517735/how-to-return-a-column-value-based-on-columns-across-multiple-worksheets)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your lookup table to the minimums only and order them ascending:

[image]

Then a simple VLOOKUP will work:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,F:G,2,TRUE)
```

[image]

---

If you insist on leaving the data as is:

```
=INDEX(G:G,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($F$2:$F$4)/((--LEFT($F$2:$F$4,FIND("-",$F$2:$F$4)-1)<=B2)*(--MID($F$2:$F$4,FIND("-",$F$2:$F$4)+1,3)>=B2)),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any formula that can convert `91-100` to `91` ?

Comment: You could use `=Left("91-100", Search("-", "91-100"))` Then just simply replace "91-100" with the proper cell. Either way, as @scott Craner mentioned, you will have to resort your data table to make his formula work.

Comment: Thanks for effort !